# WInUI - Template Studio - Page Navigation - Stop page from sliding up

Tags: winui-3, windows-template-studio

I've created a new project using "Template Studio for WinUI" extension project.

When navigating to a page, the page becomes visible and then slides up.
I don't see any behavior that could be doing this.

Anyone know how to stop that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to disable the animation transition that `Frame` offers for navigation. In order to do that, find the `NavigateTo` method in `NavigationService` (NavigationService.cs) and pass `SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo` to the `Navigate` method:

```cs
public bool NavigateTo(string pageKey, object? parameter = null, bool clearNavigation = false)
{
    var pageType = _pageService.GetPageType(pageKey);

    if (_frame != null && (_frame.Content?.GetType() != pageType || (parameter != null && !parameter.Equals(_lastParameterUsed))))
    {
        _frame.Tag = clearNavigation;
        var vmBeforeNavigation = _frame.GetPageViewModel();

        // HERE!
        var navigated = _frame.Navigate(
            pageType,
            parameter,
            new SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo());

        if (navigated)
        {
            _lastParameterUsed = parameter;
            if (vmBeforeNavigation is INavigationAware navigationAware)
            {
                navigationAware.OnNavigatedFrom();
            }
        }

        return navigated;
    }

    return false;
}
```